# java.sql.SQLException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is empty

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I need help to solve issue related to extracting data from DB using HSQLDB.
    I get error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is empty
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getColumnInType(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at DBactionSearch.actionPerformed(DBactionSearch.java:109)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: invalid cursor state: identifier cursor not positioned on row in UPDATE, DELETE, SET, or GET statement: ; ResultSet is empty
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    ... 42 more
```

Problematic part of code is:
    `text1 = rs.getString("firstname");`

When I use simple SQL expression like `SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber FROM MY_TABLE` everything works, but when I make it more complicated by adding variables in part `WHERE (SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber FROM MY_TABLE WHERE '" + columnName + "' = '" + search + "'; ")` mentioned earlier error appears.

Here is full code of class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBactionSearch implements ActionListener {

    JTextField textField1;
    JTextField textField2;
    JTextField textField3;
    public JTextField textField4;
    JTextField textField5;
    JTextField textField6;
    JTextArea textArea;
    String text1;
    String text2;
    String text3;
    String text4;
    String text5;
    String totalText;
    JComboBox comboBox;
    String search;

    public void getTextField1(JTextField textField1) {
        this.textField1 = textField1;
    }

    public void getTextField2(JTextField textField2) {
        this.textField2 = textField2;
    }

    public void getTextField3(JTextField textField3) {
        this.textField3 = textField3;
    }

    public void getTextField4(JTextField textField4) {
        this.textField4 = textField4;
    }

    public void getTextField5(JTextField textField5) {
        this.textField5 = textField5;
    }

    public void getTextField6(JTextField textField6) {
        this.textField6 = textField6;
    }

    public void setTextArea(JTextArea textArea) {
        this.textArea = textArea;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String e1 = textField1.getText();
        String e2 = textField2.getText();
        String e3 = textField3.getText();
        String e4 = textField5.getText();
        String e5 = textField6.getText();
        final String columnName = textField4.getText();

        System.out.println("columnName = " + columnName);

        switch (columnName) {
        case "firstname":
            search = e1;
            break;
        case "middlename":
            search = e2;
            break;
        case "lastname":
            search = e3;
            break;
        case "emailaddress":
            search = e4;
            break;
        case "phonenumber":
            search = e5;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        System.out.println("search = " + search);

        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:///c:/hsqldb/mydb", "SA", "");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(
                    "SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber FROM MY_TABLE WHERE '"
                            + columnName + "' = '" + search + "'; ");

            rs.next();
            // while (rs.next()) {
            text1 = rs.getString("firstname");
            text2 = rs.getString("middlename");
            text3 = rs.getString("lastname");
            text4 = rs.getString("emailaddress");
            text5 = rs.getString("phonenumber");
            // }

            // while (rs.next()) {
            // System.out.println(rs.getRow() + ". " + rs.getString("TITLE")
            // + "\t" + rs.getString("AUTHOR"));
            // }
        }

        catch (Exception excepton) {
            excepton.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Search result");
        frame3.setSize(350, 350);
        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame3.setLocation(500, 250);
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        frame3.add(panel2);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        panel2.add(textArea);
        textArea.setVisible(true);

        totalText = " '" + text1 + "'   \n   '" + text2 + "'  \n   '" + text3 + "' \n" + " '" + text4 + "'  \n  '"
                + text5 + "' ";
        System.out.println("totalText = " + totalText);
        textArea.setText(totalText);

        frame3.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are, as far as I can see it, two mistakes in your code.

Firstly, you are not building up the SQL query correctly.  Try printing it out before you send it off to the database.  You'll find that you get something like the following:

```
SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber FROM MY_TABLE WHERE 'middlename' = 'Fred';
```

Spot the mistake?  (Scroll right.)

You are selecting all rows from `MY_TABLE` where the strings `middleName` and (in this case) `Fred` are equal.  Of course, these strings are not equal, so you get no matching rows.

You probably wanted to run the following query:

```
SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname, emailaddress, phonenumber FROM MY_TABLE WHERE middlename = 'Fred';
```

Note that there are no longer any quotes around `middlename`, so `middlename` is now being interpreted as a column name rather than as a string.  If this is what you want, remove the single quotes in your SQL string on either side of the `columnName` variable.

The second problem is here:

```
        rs.next();
```

You're not bothering to check whether you're getting any results back.  By returning `false` from this method, HSQL was telling you that there was no data. However, you chose not to listen to this and to proceed with reading data out regardless.

What you want to write instead is something like the following:

```
        if (rs.next()) {
            // read the data out of the result set.
        } else {
            // handle the case that no matching data was found.
        }
```

Comment: This helped. Thank you.